# php postgresql using cache

Tags: php, postgresql

- I have a php page with lot of queries and takes 2-3 minutes to load.
- The database to which queries are hiting is updated once a month (1st
  of every month).
- The page hits different schemas of database depending on user selection (User selects options from select box depending on which different schema's of db are used).
- So, if the database is updated once a month, means after that same result per input selection are displayed till next month.

Is there any solution (caching etc.) so that if any of the client has generated that page, it is used for remaning days instead of hitting queries again ?

Comment: Firstly nothing you're building should take that long to load.  You likely just need to properly index your tables.  Secondly, what you're asking for is a bit unclear, as far as the month by month stuff goes.  Like the report should be the same all month, and then next month different?

Comment: Actually there are 95-100 database schema's thats why it is taking time. And yes there are 50-60 reports which are going to be same entire month.

Comment: Well firstly, unless those 95-100 DB schemas are processing a few 100 million records a month each, it still shouldn't take more than a few seconds with proper indexing.  Secondly, if they're truly separate schemas, async processing is your friend.  Thirdly, yes you should just make a 1 time agrigate report with a cron job and then use that for the rest of the month.

Comment: Post the explain on one of the queries, I guarantee your data model is the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

2-3 minutes it's too long, this means your database is not optimized. You should make right indexes for your tables, need to analyze your queries and according to it create indexes for tables.

Also you can create temporary view which will contain data from your most frequent queries. Refresh it once per month or every big update of your data in DB.

Create cron task which will be executed once per month to recreated updated view. Then make queries from that generated view.

Also you can think about replication if there are a lot of select queries, try to separate them between several servers to reduce the load.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be able to just write the output to a file and just have a seperate command line script that generates the reports once a month.

A example of someone doing this in php is at https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/09/php-cache-dynamic-pages-speed-up-load-times, although I'm sure there are lots of others out there :)